# Tile server stops working

Tags: rendering, server, mod-tile

I built my own tile server and when I try to prerender zoom level 10 or 13 modtile/renderd just stops working (like when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal).
The other levels work fine.

OS: Lubuntu 14.04

Style: OpenTopoMap

Command to start modtile/renderd:

```
sudo -u renderuser renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
```

Command to start prerendering (for example lvl 10):
sudo -u renderuser render_list -a -z 10 -Z 10 -s /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock

So I start `modtile` and after that render_list. It starts doing stuff and rendering some tiles. But after some time both stop working, as you seen in the following screenshot:

[image: Tile server stopped]

Is there a way to see why it stopped?

Has somebody faced the same problems?

Has somebody a idea how to get it working?